# change css when no data from mysql is being recieved

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql

my overall goal from the below code is when data is pulled in the value of beacon will correspond with a number in the table and location will change the background colour based on its value, the border will be changed based on a delivery_avg value and then when the data has stopped being pulled in the cells will go back to grey background and black thin border ( see code below for current idea and see the pictures attached for example data and default table layout)

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Table Tracker</title>
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.0.5/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script>html5.addElements('latest_beacons')</script>
<![endif]-->

<style>
td.flash{
animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
from, to { box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 white;}
100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px white inset; }
}
table {
padding: 10px 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;    
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 40px;
background-color: #8F8F8F;
}
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
    for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
    }
}
$.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
console.log(response);
//checks if key is in array
if("location" in response){
  $.each(response, function(index, item) {
    $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).addClass('coloured');
  });
}else{
  console.log("key not found");
  //change your css here when no value exists
  //IMPORTANT Note what I have placed here is an example and might not work
  $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F',{'border-color':'black', 'border-width':'thin' }).addClass('coloured');
}
});


function updateTable() {
    //console.log('function called');
    $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F',{'border-color':'black', 'border-width':'thin' }).toggleClass('coloured');
    $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(index, item) {
            console.log(item.beacon);
            if(item.location){
                $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
              if (item.delivery_avg <= 4.00) {
               return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
              } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 4.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 7.00) {
               return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'orange', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
              } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 7.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
               return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'pink', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
              } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 10.01) {
               return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'red', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
              }                
            }

        });
    });
}
var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});
</script>
</head>

 <body>
<table id='zoning'>
        <tbody></tbody>
</table>
 </body>

</html>
```

[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K2B9.png)[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI9zI.png)

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` output if there is no value inside your `$.get()`?

Comment: i have added an image of the console when data is being pulled in and when there is no longer data being pulled in nothing is displayed in the console.

Comment: When you get the array `{beacon..}` defines nothing?

Comment: Or is it the location is not present?

Comment: Just trying using ` css() ` and `addClass() ` function seperately. Dont do them at same line

Comment: so when data is pulled in beacon will match with the corresponding number in the table and location will be a colour that the background of the cell will change to, when the data has stopped being pulled in the console doesn't update bar text that says functioncalled to show that the update has re run but no data has been collected

Comment: @AnikethSaha could you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

okay you want to check if the key is in your response:

Try this:

```
$.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    //checks if key is in array
    if("location" in response){
      $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).addClass('coloured');
      });
    }else{
      console.log("key not found");
      //change your css here when no value exists
      //IMPORTANT Note what I have placed here is an example and might not work
      $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color','#8F8F8F',{'border-color':'black', 'border-width':'thin' });
    }
});
```

Inside your `updateTable` function you need to test for the key yet again. You have two locations where you use `$.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {` hence why it's crashing again. I placed an if statement around the area to check if item.location exists. I'm not sure why you're using doing this twice. However I hope this minor change will fix the issue.

```
    function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-color':'#8F8F8F',{'border-color':'black', 'border-width':'thin' }).toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                console.log(item.beacon);
                if(item.location){
                    $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
                  if (item.delivery_avg <= 4.00) {
                   return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
                  } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 4.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 7.00) {
                   return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'orange', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
                  } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 7.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
                   return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'pink', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
                  } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 10.01) {
                   return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color':'red', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
                  }                
                }else{
                  $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color','#8F8F8F',{'border-color':'black', 'border-width':'thin' });
                }

            });
        });
    }
```